# Can we use any Id other then Salesforce Id to query object for Integration while using Partner WSDL?

Tags: partner-wsdl

Can we use any Id other than Salesforce Id to query object for Integration while using Partner WSDL. e.g. Can we use an external field (e.g. Customer ID) to query Account inside Salesforce using SOAP API?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

You can SOQL to query Account records on any condition. [You can test Partner WSDL directly using soapUI without writing any code](http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/using-soapui-with-salesforce-to-test-standard-and-custom-web-services-response/).

Answer (score 0):

And you should also make the respective field as External ID and Unique that way you will not have an runtime errors because of bad data.

Comment: You can find more details about [External Id](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=faq_import_general_what_is_an_external.htm)